# How to P/invoke double*

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, pinvoke

I am trying to call a C++ method from C#. Unfortunately, the documentation for the C++ library is pretty skimpy, but I have access to a header file that defines the methods, so.

The C++ declaration is:

```
DWORD FAR PASCAL EXPORT Init(int numOfChannels,int startLead,int smpRate,double* pMV_in_1_NUM,int mode  = 0);
```

The documentation unfortunately only gives a C++ example for using this method, which is:

```
Init (8, 1, 500, &pMV_in_1_NUM, 1);
```

But I'm trying to call it from C#, so my code is:

```
[DllImport("NVECGUSB.dll", EntryPoint = "Init")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
private static extern UInt32 Init(
    int numOfChannels,
    int startLead,
    int smpRate,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    ref double pMV_in_1_NUM,
    int mode
    );
```

and then...

```
double pmvIn1Num = 0;
resultCode = Init(8, 1, 500, ref pmvIn1Num, 1);
Console.WriteLine("Init returned {0}", resultCode.ToString("x"));
```

It doesn't crash or anything, but the `resultCode` is indicating that the parameters are incorrect, even though they values are correct according to the documentation, so I'm guessing there's something wrong with how I'm passing that `double *` parameter. (I'm willing to accept that I'm wrong there but right now I can't think of another reason for the error)

Note that I've also tried

```
[DllImport("NVECGUSB.dll", EntryPoint = "Init")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
private static extern UInt32 Init(
    int numOfChannels,
    int startLead,
    int smpRate,
    double[] pMV_in_1_NUM,
    int mode
    );
```

and

```
double[] pmvIn1Num = new double[] { 0 };
resultCode = Init(6, 1, 250, pmvIn1Num, 1);
```

because Google searches throw up results about arrays of double, but I'm not sure this is applicable in my scenario.

So my question is, am I doing it correctly?

(Note that this relates to the Norav 1200M ECG device so if someone has worked wiht that and can tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be great too)

Comment: Also,  you need to establish whether the `double *` denotes an array or a simple "out" parameter.  From the C++ example, it seems to denote an "out" parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `PASCAL` maps to `__stdcall` on Win32, assuming `<windows.h>` is used to supply the definition. It used to be a different calling convention, but that's a legacy of Win16. (As is the `FAR`.)

Comment: `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)` should go. The parameter is a *pointer* to a double, not an actual double. I don't know exactly what the marshaler does with this attribute when misapplied, so it may well make no difference, but it's certainly doing no good either. `ref double` and `out double` should be marshaled correctly without a need for further attributes.

Comment: Same with the return value. `Uint32` is already marshaled as a 4byte integer, there is no reason to explicitly marshal it using `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)`. Don't use `MarshalAs` unless you actually need it to specify marshaling behavior that is different than the default behavior.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right, I was looking at the `_MAC` definition of `PASCAL`, which is blank.  When `_MAC` is not defined, `PASCAL` and `pascal` both map to `__stdcall` if the compiler supports `__stdcall`, otherwise they are blank.